# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following code, which is making an HTTP call and returns a promise

```
const res = simulations.getSimulationRunAssets({
  path: this.props.commonProps.apiPath,
  apiVersion: DEFAULT_API_VERSION,
  simulationRunId
});
console.log('**** res', res);

res
  .then(data => {
    console.log('2SimulationRun populateSimulationRun getsimulation run assets data', data);
    if (!data) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('No data received from the API.'));
    }
```

The console output shows that a prmoise is being returned:

```
**** res Promise {<pending>}
...
2SimulationRun populateSimulationRun getsimulation run assets data 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{id: 1, name: "H..."}
...
```

but then I get the following in the console:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
```

right in the following line (res.then(data => {):

```
res
> 91 |   .then(data => {
```

getSimulationRunAssets:

```
const getSimulationRunAssets = ({ path, apiVersion, simulationRunId }) => {
  const urlPath = `${path}${apiVersion}/simulation-runs/${simulationRunId}/assets`;

  console.log('GET Simulation Run Assets API Call', `${urlPath}`);

  const promise = axios
    .get(urlPath)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('GET Simulation Run Assets Response', res);
      if (res.status !== 200) {
        const err = new Error('Error retrieving simulation run assets');
        err.response = res;
        throw err;
      }
      console.log('getSimulationRunAssets returning res.data', res.data);
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      if (err.response && err.response.data && err.response.data.message) {
        err = new verror.VError(err, err.response.data.message);
      }
      console.log('Rejecting');
      console.log('getSimulationRunAssets returning rejecting', err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
  console.log('getSimulationRunAssets returning promise', promise);
  return promise;
};
```

Comment: Looks like that rejection is generated simulations.getSimulationRunAssets().  I don't see anywhere in your code where this type of error is being thrown.

Comment: @Jim B., I just pasted that function above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in Chrome wasn't very helpful.  When I switched to Firefox, I could see that the error was coming from getSimulationRunAssets().  The Firefox error said that arr wasn't defined.

```
[currentAsset] = data.name;
```

should have been:

```
currentAsset = data[0].name;
```